# How do I know if CopyToDataTable doesn't have rows so that blank pages don't appear in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datatable, row

How do I know if CopyToDataTable doesn't have rows so that blank pages don't appear in vb.net?

is there something wrong with my code?

Below is also the solution code but how can I implement it with my code.
Thanks

```
'I found the code solution below but I didn't implement it in my code 
                If payslips.LastOrDefault() IsNot payslip Then
                    report.NewPage()
                End If
```

```
  Private Sub Generate()
        Dim dt As New DataTable()
        report.Clear()
        Dim query = "Select EMPID,[NAME],MONTHLYSALARY From tblemployee"
        Using adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(query, Con)
            adapter.Fill(dt)
        End Using
        For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
            Dim table = {row}.CopyToDataTable()
  report.AddDataTable(table)
            report.NewPage()
        Next row
    End Sub
```

[image: output preview in page 4 is blank]

[image: blank page in page three]

Comment: Your question makes no sense as it's asked. The reason you can't work out a solution is because you're looking at the problem all wrong in the first place. It's not the case that `CopyToDataTable` has rows or doesn't. You're calling the method on an array that contains a row so there's ALWAYS a row to copy to the `DataTable`. I already explained this to you in another question but you didn't listen. There is a page by default and every time you call `NewPage` you add another page. If there are three rows then 1+3=4, so it's obvious why you have four rows.

Comment: You only want to call `NewPage` when you actually want a new page. You don't want a new page after adding the last row so don't call `NewPage`. One obvious option for that is to use a `For` loop and then call `NewPage` based on the row index, i.e. don't call it if the index is for the last page.

Comment: @jmcilhinney , If I don't call "report. NewPage()" then I don't separate each "EMP ID". The new page solution for blank pages is according to the code example I posted but I can't apply it because I use copytodatatable. How can I apply the row index datatable according to the report?

Comment: I already showed you how to use a `For` loop to do this in one of your other questions, because you can't use a `For each` loop when there are two source lists. If you do what I showed you there then you've already got a row index so you can use that exactly as I said above.

Comment: I didn't tell you not to call it. I told you not to call it after adding the last `DataTable`. If there's 3 rows then you want 3 pages. There is 1 page by default so you want to add 2 pages. At the moment, you're adding 3 pages. I can't keep repeating myself when the words are available for you to read as many times as you need to. Use a `For` loop and add a new page if and only if you didn't just add the last row. I've already provided all you need so I'm bowing out.

Comment: The one additional thing I will say is that, instead of adding the page break last, you could add it first. In that case you would NOT add it for the first page, so you would still test the row index but you'd look for 0 instead of 1 less than the row count, so it will be a bit simpler. In fact, I'll add an answer to this effect to avoid heartache for everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point here is that, every time you call `NewPage`, a new page is added. If there is one page by default and you call `NewPage` for every row, you're going to end up with one more page than rows, which is exactly what you're seeing.

A solution is to call BEFORE adding the data to be printed on that page, if and only if a new page is needed. Ther first row will be printed on the default page, so you'll only need to call `NewPage` for the second row and later. By using a `For` loop instead of a `For Each` loop, you have a row index that you can test to determine whether you're on the first row or not:

```vb
For i = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
    Dim row = dt.Rows(i)

    If i > 0 Then
        'We are not on the first row so we need a new page.
        report.NewPage()
    End If

    '...
Next
```

Comment: The answer from runs very perfectly so I call newpage before my report.adddatatable or before the existence of record data